# Can't start Raspberry Pi OS

Tags: boot-issues

When I try to boot the Pi, I get this error:
[image]

Comment: Poor question, no detail.

Comment: Post text, not out of focus photos.

Comment: @Dougie - you expect someone to type out what's on the boot screen? bit harsh

Answer (score -4):

For anyone coming here in the future: the way to fix it is Go to Raspberry Pi Imager, scroll to the bottom of the OS list, click on Misc. Utility images, Click on SD, USB, or Network boot. Put the sd/thumb drive in the pi until the screen is green.

Comment: Poor answer, doesn't explain what you did to fix the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this would be a pi4 recovery image? so, useless information for a pi 0,1,2,3?